# Default to using small med packs in Dead Space 3?

Tags: dead-space-3

I'm playing Dead Space 3 on PC and every time I hit <kbd>Q</kbd> to use a medpack, it seems to use the largest one I have.  However, I've got a bunch of small medpacks taking up space.

Is it possible to change the default behavior to use a small med back first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I never figured out how to change the medpack quick heal uses, I did discover I could manually use the smallest med packs from my inventory screen.  This allowed me to save my med/large medpacks for points when I really needed them.

Answer (score 3):

> In Dead Space, pressing the "quick-heal" button automatically uses the
>   smallest Med Pack in the player's inventory, while in Dead Space 2 and
>   3, it uses the medium Med Pack if two or more health bars are missing
>   and the small one if only one bar is missing; the large Pack is
>   selected only if it is the only one remaining, it must be used
>   manually otherwise.

directly from the dead space wiki: http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Medical_Packs

Comment: I found that when my health was in the red, quick heal always used the largest available medpack.